# Magento 2 add coupon by default to all order?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders

How to add a default coupon to all order. Will it be an observer?

Comment: Use `no coupon`

Comment: Can you explain more details? still confusing about your question.

Comment: I want to add coupon code TEST123 to all order by default. User will see it applied. They did't hv to add it manually.

Comment: Provided link is on Magento1, but you can use the logic to impliment an extension http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/how-to-apply-magento-coupon-codes-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

This block of code worked for my solution

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');  
$salesRuleFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory');
$salesRule = $salesRuleFactory->create();
$salesRuleId = 2;
$salesRule->load($salesRuleId);
$couponCode = $salesRule->getPrimaryCoupon()->getCode();

$cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode(trim($couponCode));
$cart->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
```